# Switch Stylesheet and Content Section with one click

Tags: javascript, php, html

im trying to switch the stylesheet.css and the content section at the same time, if the user click on a Section on the Top-menue bar.

If I do one of them alone, it works fine, but both together will not work at the moment.

In my index.php I have a function that set the Stylesheet:

```
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function swapStyleSheet (sheet) {
            document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
            return;
        }
    </script>
```

In the Menu.php is the code for changing the section and it also calls the function above. The Categories are in a list.

```
<li><a href="index.php?section=section_games" onclick="swapStyleSheet('Games.css'); return false;">Games</a></li>
```

With the return false statement the Style switch correct, but not the Content selection. And if I remove the return false statement the Content is correct but the Style switches only for a little moment.

Can somebody help me, please!

Comment: Just a sidenote: That anchor (<a>) is pointing to another page, therefore it will reload the page. As a result, by reloading the page, your function (which won't work in any case) will be literally useless, because the page is refreshed.

Comment: _“if I remove the return false statement the Content is correct but the Style switches only for a little moment”_ – of course, because then the link triggers loading of a new page, and in that your stylesheet has not been switched … You need to either use AJAX to load the link content via script in the background and place it in the current document, or simply stop switching out the stylesheet client-side and have your server do it on the new page. (Or not switch the stylesheet at all, but have one for all pages, which in most cases would make the most sense.)

Comment: Wouldn't setting the `href` to `#` work?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys! It works now...

I load the Stylesheet now in the php file for every section in the  tag with onload. Looks like this:

```
<body onload="swapStyleSheet('Game.css')">
```

Comment: Sounds like nonsense … why not have a “normal” `link` element that refers the stylesheet inside each document in the first place?

Comment: Yes, you right! Thats an simple way. I thought too complicated... Thank you!